# Is this solution to a seating / PigeonHole question correct?

Tags: solution-verification, problem-solving, pigeonhole-principle

The question asks:
Suppose there are 1350 people seated in a row of 2021 chairs. Prove that there are 3 consecutive non-empty (taken) chairs.

Here was my logic: Assume (by contradiction) that the there are no 3 consecutively taken chairs. So the most taken chairs we can have consecutively is 2. Now, the seating that will satisfy this whilst taking up the least amount of "space" is placing an empty chair between every pair of people. Something like this, where A is a person sitting in a chair and each _ is an empty chair:
AA_AA_AA_AA_ and so on.
Now, there are 675 pairs of people, and each pair (except for the last one) needs to have an empty chair following them. This seating arrangement would require 674*2 + 674 = 2022 chairs (the number of people + the number of empty chairs) which is more than we have.

Contradiction. So there must be at least one instance of 3 consecutive non-empty chairs. In another line of thinking, by the pigeonhole principle, 1 person must "share" with an empty chair and therefore fill one of the empty chairs separating 2 pairs of people, which leads to 3 consecutive non-empty chairs.

Is this correct? I submitted this solution for a math class and received a very low grade, as if my reasoning were completely off. I'd like to know if I'm missing something.

Comment: Why don’t you ask your teacher for the specific reason?

I see an unimportant problem: Your chair count is off by $2$, as you do not count the last pair at all (it should be $675\cdot2+674$). Then the other problem: You seem to assume that alternating two chairs taken, one empty requires the least amount of chairs under these assumptions. While that is technically true, maybe you’d be expected to prove that?

Comment: @Lazy I definitely will ask him, I just wanted to see if there was anything I could do to refine my approach. So, I don't count the last pair on purpose. This is because the last pair does not need to have an empty chair to the right of them (if the row just ends then that's fine, it's still only 2 consecutive non-empty chairs). And even if I did count them, that's even more chairs required, so it would still lead to a contradiction. As for the 2nd point, isn't that obvious? Maybe that is it... But it seems clear to me that you have to have an empty chair between every 2 at LEAST (cont)

Comment: pt 2: and adding any more would take up more space. You could be right though, maybe he did want more justification for that (though I don't see why). If those are the only issues, I'll definitely talk to him and try to defend my solution.

Comment: I did say it was an unimportant problem, as it increases chairs, but even though they do not need an empty chair to the right, they still need chairs. And $675\cdot 2$ are the chairs people are sitting on, $674$ are the required empty chairs.

Comment: And I’m aware that this property is quite obvious, one easy way to argue this is to take a second ordering and compare it with your ordering. At the first place they differ (which must then be the perfect ordering has an occupied chair and the given placement doesn’t) you can then without changing the numbers of chairs switch the next occupied seat with that one. Thus you eventually get a new ordering that uses the same amount of chairs as the given one, but starts with the perfect one (and might have some empty chairs at the end).

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. On the actual quiz, I actually wrote 675*2+674. So 2024 spaces required. I thought I messed up then with that but I realize now I messed up while typing this question! Thanks for explaining.                                              It seems clear that there are no *glaring* problems with this, though. Thank you for your feedback. I'll definitely talk to my professor about it.